# Issues with accessibility keyboard input on Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, accessibility

I've been building an app using React Native, and we're making sure that it was highly accessible.  When we tried testing it using a keyboard to navigate on Android, though, we were unable to activate any buttons.  We tried reproducing it using the simplest app, and the issue was still there.  We were able to reproduce the issue with React Native versions `0.41.0`-`0.44.0`.  We have tried every combination of props on our `TouchableOpacity` elements, as well as trying `Button` elements, and have not had any success.

With an android phone with TalkBack on and a bluetooth keyboard connected, take these steps:

- `react-native init myProject`
- `cd myProject`
- Edit `index.android.js` to add a `<TouchableOpacity>` tag with a handler that you can test, like making an alert box
- `react-native run-android`
- Navigate to the touchable element and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> if using an old enough flavor of Android)

Notice that your handler is not fired when using the keyboard, but you can still trigger the element by double-tapping on the screen.

Here is my `index.android.js` for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class myProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('test')}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Click me!
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myProject', () => myProject);
```

Does anyone know how to get the keyboard to trigger this event as expected?

Comment: Without being able to see or test this myself: why do you have to double-tap? I would expect using a keyboard to activate something to be equivalent to a single tap.

Comment: @Dane with TalkBack on, the way you activate a button is by double tapping.  Single tapping will only change the focus to the tapped element.

Comment: @kevin.groat : Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @MossPalmer I never was able to figure this out, unfortunately.

Comment: @kevin.groat It was a long shot. Thanks for getting back to me though.